# Using map in Perl to map only if key exists

Tags: perl, dictionary, perl-data-structures

I have a data structure that has been defined like this:

```
my @columns = (
  {
    db => 'location',
    dt => 'location',
    search => 'location',
  },
  {
    db => 'name',
    dt => 'name',
    search => 'name',
  },
  {
    db => 'iqs',
    dt => 'iqs',
  },
);
```

I am mapping the values of search like so:

```
@where = map +{ $_->{search} => { like => "\%$global_search\%" } }, @columns;
```

If the key search does not exist, I end up with a data structure that has a bunch of these:

```
{
    '' => {
        'like' => '%pas%'
    }
},
```

And that completely screws up what I am trying to do. So, I am wondering, since map isn't technically a loop, how can I skip when the key search does not exist?

**EDIT:**

Someone below had asked about performance differences between map vs loop, and this piqued my curiosity, so I decided to test it myself. Here are the results:

**The Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark qw/cmpthese timethese/;

my $global_search = 'test';


my @columns;
for ( my $i = 0; $i <= 100000; $i++ ) {
    my $hash = {
        db => "test$i",
        dt => "test$i",
        search => "test$i"
    };
    push @columns, $hash;
}

timethese(-30, {
      mapBuild => sub {
        my @where = map {
          exists ($_->{search})
            ? +{ $_->{search} => { like => "\%$global_search\%" } }
            : ()
        } @columns;
      },
      forBuild => sub {
        my @where;
        foreach (@columns) {
          if (exists $_->{search}) {
            push @where, +{ $_->{search} => { like => "\%$global_search\%" } } ;
          }
        }
      },
});

cmpthese(-30, {
      mapBuild => sub {
        my @where = map {
          exists ($_->{search})
            ? +{ $_->{search} => { like => "\%$global_search\%" } }
            : ()
        } @columns;
      },
      forBuild => sub {
        my @where;
        foreach (@columns) {
          if (exists $_->{search}) {
            push @where, +{ $_->{search} => { like => "\%$global_search\%" } } ;
          }
        }
      },
});
```

**The Results**

> Benchmark: running forBuild, mapBuild for at least 30 CPU seconds...
>   forBuild: 32 wallclock secs (31.66 usr +  0.00 sys = 31.66 CPU) @
>   980.35/s (n=31038)   mapBuild: 31 wallclock secs (31.58 usr +  0.00 sys = 31.58 CPU) @ 994.21/s (n=31397)
>             Rate forBuild mapBuild forBuild 978/s       --      -2% mapBuild 993/s       2%       --

Comment: I answered my own question mere seconds after posting this. I will leave it here in case anyone else is looking for the answer:  `@where = map +{ $_->{search} => { like => "\%$global_search\%" } }, grep { exists $_->{search} } @columns;`  

However, considering Perl and TMTOWTDI, I'd be interested in other ways people might accomplish this.

Comment: `grep` before `map`, or map returning empty list `()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The block passed to `map` gets called in list context, so it can return an empty list:

```
@where = map {
   exists ($_->{search})
      ? +{ $_->{search} => { like => "\%$global_search\%" } }
      : ()
} @columns;
```

Or you could just `grep` first:

```
@where =
   map +{ $_->{search} => { like => "\%$global_search\%" } },
   grep exists($_->{search}),
   @columns;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@where = map {
    $_->{search} => { like => "\%$global_search\%" }
} grep {
    defined $_->{search}
} @columns;
```

Answer (score 1):

Could always try turning it into a loop that reads more like English.

```
my @where;

for (@columns) {
    if ( exists $_->{search} ) {
        push @where, +{ $_->{search} => { like => "\%$global_search\%" } };
    }
}
```

Does anyone know if there's a huge performance hit from doing what I just wrote, or it roughly the same speed as map?

Comment: Good catch! That would produce some interesting results during testing.

Comment: Your question about performance differences piqued my interest. I decided to test with my use case, and map was ever-so slightly faster. I edited my original question to add the code and results.

Comment: @ShawnCarinchuck It's roughly the same.  Either way, I'd call the question a [premature optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) concern.  One should focus first on making code readable and easy to understand.  Even if one was faster in the current version of Perl, there would be no guarantee that it would still be in a later one.